# Trigger when performing action from specific account

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code to perform action when replying, forwarding and composing an email:

```vb
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set myItem = Item
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub myItem_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    msgbox ("hello world")
End Sub
```

I would like add recipient in CC when replying, forwarding or composing a new message from a particular account.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property. If it is null, you can assume that the default account (`Application.Session.Accounts(1))` is being used.